# cant send data from jquery to c# server

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, json, web

been trying to make a jquery validatation for correct input and server validation to check if user/email exists. only problem is that the parameters are not always sent from the client side for some reason even after this passes the jquery validation.
tried enter breaking point in the beginning of the server side method, rarely enters there, placed alert after inserting data to params and sees the json looks OK.
im using Jquery, asp.net, c#.

client code:

```
var user = $("#txt_register_username").val();
            var password = $("#txt_register_password").val();
            var firstname = $("#txt_register_firstname").val();
            var lastname = $("#txt_register_lastname").val();
            var birthdate = $("#txt_register_birthdate").val();
            var picture = $("#txt_register_picture").val();
            var car = $("#txt_register_car").val();
            var email = $("#txt_register_email").val();
            var home = $("#txt_register_home").val();
            var cell = $("#txt_register_cell").val();
            var params = "{username:" + user
            + ",firstname:" + firstname
            + ",lastname:" + lastname
            + ",birthdate:" + birthdate
            + ",pic:123"
            + ",carowned:" + car
            + ",email:" + email
            + ",password:" + password
            + ",home:" + home
            + ",cell:" + cell
            + "}";
            $.ajax
            ({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Register.aspx/AddUser",
                data: params,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dateType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(result.d);

                }
            });
```

the pic will later be binary, so its just temporary, ignore it for being string.

server code:

```
[WebMethod]
        public static string AddUser(string username, string firstname, string lastname, string birthdate, string pic, string carowned, string email, string password, string home, string cell)
        {
            DataSet1TableAdapters.UsersTableAdapter userAdapter = new DataSet1TableAdapters.UsersTableAdapter();
            DataSet1.UsersDataTable userTable = new DataSet1.UsersDataTable();
            userAdapter.Fill(userTable);
            int index = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("entering valiation area");
            foreach (DataRow dr in userTable.Rows)
            {
                if (userTable.Rows[index]["username"].Equals(username))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("a user who already exists tried to create an account");
                    return "user already exists with that username";        
                }
                if (userTable.Rows[index]["email"].Equals(email))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("a user who already exists with an email tried to create an account");
                    return "user already exists with that email";
                }
                index++;
            }
            try
            {
                userAdapter.Insert(username, firstname, lastname, birthdate, pic, carowned, email, password, home, cell);
                Console.WriteLine("new user added to db");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                return "oops , something went wrong.";
            }
            return "new user added to database.";

        }
```

Comment: what error do you get. show the error?

Comment: show your button and jquery code (button click)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try;

```
var params = JSON.stringify({
             username:user,
            firstname :firstname,
            lastname:lastname,
            birthdate: birthdate,
            pic:123,
            carowned:car,
            email:email,
            password: password,
            home: home,
            cell: cell
           });
```

Comment: 1 more question, after trying to that couple of times im getting error in the server side on the row of userAdapter.Fill(userTable) and it says ConstraintExepetion was unhandled by the user... and all of my fields are good, nothing null..

Comment: put your code in try cat block or use visual studio debugger and step line by line

Comment: it seems from exception that there is some constraint (e.g length, unique) in your database field and this data is voilating

Comment: ok its wierd, when i entering by autofill my email it creates the user but next time i press adding user it gets thi error.. my database define nvarchar(70) for this field and im just entering a normal email...ideas?

Comment: hhmmm? looks like you have to post it in another question. so we can see the code

Answer (score 1):

Try switching to this syntax:

```
var params = {"username" : user,
              "firstname" : firstname
              ....
             };
```

jQuery's data expects a json object to parse into server variables.

Comment: nop..doesnt help. i could create few account with my syntax, but there is probably an exeption or something that prevent me from sending data.. im not using any /:', or something like that.

Comment: I just noticed that you have "dateType" instead of "dataType". No idea if that's the cause, but probably wouldn't hurt to fix.

Answer (score 0):

You should send your data in json object but you are sending it as a string!
Switch your syntax to something like this:

```
var params = {username: + user
            ,firstname: + firstname
            ,lastname: + lastname
            ,birthdate: + birthdate
            ,pic:123
            ,carowned: + car
            ,email: + email
            ,password: + password
            ,home: + home
            ,cell: + cell
            };
```

**Edit:**
If I were you I would remove dataType property to see how it works!

Comment: register button doesnt even execute... i think visual studio in not familiar with that.

Comment: why `+` in between variable

Comment: @OriGavrielRefael, try `CauseValidation` to false (of the button)

Answer (score 0):

It's due to your AJAX call being a "POST", rather than "GET", so the parameters are treated differently.

You need something like:

```
var data = $.toJSON(params);
```

then send the `data` object with the AJAX request, rather than `params`.

Comment: register button doesnt even execute

Answer (score 0):

As Jeremy mentioned your JSON is incorrect

it needs to be something like this
{"username" : "user",
              "firstname" : "firstname"
              ....
             }

download fiddler and you will be able to see what issue you are getting, you will then be able to take the posted json and run it through JSONLint.com which will tell you why your json is formed incorrectly.

Also get json2.js and then you can do what dotnet dreamer has shown you, stringify may be built into some of the newer browsers, think firefox has it but older browsers like ie8 and below don't, it may now be built into jquery so I would check first, haven't done much ajax stuff lately